# How to test the Date, Month and Year entered as 2 Digits are valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

In my form, a user can enter the date like this: `220875` (day, month, year).

Once they entered the details, I would like to test that the date is valid:

1. Month is from 1 to 12 inclusive.
2. The day entered is valid for the specified month.

How would I find out whether or not the values are correct and matching?

here is my attempt: (excerpt)

```
DateIsOk:function(value) { //220875 for example
        var formatValue = value.match(/.{1,2}/g), //splting as 22 08 75
         fieldDate = parseInt(formatValue[0]), //converting to num
         fieldMonth = parseInt(formatValue[1]),
         fieldYear = parseInt(formatValue[2]),
         dayobj = new Date();

        //test need to go here...
    }
```

If it helps, here is a [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/q7QmZ/1/).

Comment: Are you asking how to do `if (fieldMonth > 12)`?

Comment: I am trying to validate using Date object. is that possible?, especially sending the value like this new Date(ddmmyy), because in feb will get even 28 days right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you use the DD/MM/YYYY format.

So you can easily use this ready-to-use code: http://www.qodo.co.uk/blog/javascript-checking-if-a-date-is-valid/

**JavaScript**

```
// Checks a string to see if it in a valid date format
// of (D)D/(M)M/(YY)YY and returns true/false
function isValidDate(s) {
    // format D(D)/M(M)/(YY)YY
    var dateFormat = /^\d{1,4}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,2}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,4}$/;

    if (dateFormat.test(s)) {
        // remove any leading zeros from date values
        s = s.replace(/0*(\d*)/gi,"$1");
        var dateArray = s.split(/[\.|\/|-]/);

        // correct month value
        dateArray[1] = dateArray[1]-1;

        // correct year value
        if (dateArray[2].length<4) {
            // correct year value
            dateArray[2] = (parseInt(dateArray[2]) < 50) ? 2000 + parseInt(dateArray[2]) : 1900 + parseInt(dateArray[2]);
        }

        var testDate = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1], dateArray[0]);
        if (testDate.getDate()!=dateArray[0] || testDate.getMonth()!=dateArray[1] || testDate.getFullYear()!=dateArray[2]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [`momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/) *as @hVostt suggested*, you could try modifying your `DateIsOk()` validation function like this:

```
...
dateParts : ["years", "months", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds", "milliseconds"],
DateIsOk:function(value) {        
    var dayobj = moment(value, "DDMMYY");

    if (dayobj.isValid()) {
        this.errorHandler(true);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        this.errorHandler('Invalid ' + this.dateParts[dayobj.invalidAt()]);
        return false;
    }
}
...
```

Here's the updated [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7QmZ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The js regexp maybe like this

`/([0-2][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\d{2})/`

Comment: I agree. by independent base it check the value. as a example if i give the date "300275" - there is no "30" in feb. it gives as 'true'.

Comment: yes,the Feb problem will be resolved with a patched js check.Maybe you can add it after the regexp test. But another problem is that Feb has different number of days in different year. It must be checked specially.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and his validation functions:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/

```
moment([2014, 25, 35]).isValid();

moment("2014-25-35").isValid();
```